# NextJS 13 node backend fetch api not using port

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js13

My problem is that if I call a fetch function like fetch(“/api/blog/“) I get te response 404 not found. The api route is on the backend on port 5000. I have the nextjs config rewrite rule which works perfect with redux. But with fetch function it tries to reach port 3000.

In the config I have the source: /api/:path* and the destination is http://localhost:5000/:path*

An as I mentioned it works fine with react-redux.

Any ideas?

Thanks